# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: name provided was not in the list of valid column labels:

Tags: java, database, hadoop, cassandra, cql

my query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM datasquare.users WHERE email_id = '"yup@krish.com"' and 
password = '"krish"' ALLOW FILTERING
```

my table

```
 email_id        | password | user_id | user_name
-----------------+----------+---------+-----------
 vamsi@gmail.com |  krishna |    2915 |     vamsi
```

Comment: The description of the exception is explicit and you're not showing us your real code, so currently there's no way we can help you.

Comment: im working for a login page with cassandra db

Comment: Please provide the relevant code to replicate the error, this implicates proper Java code. Where you use this code and why may be part of the explanation of the issue, but not provide any direct guideline for us to help you.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the name of your Java driver, output of `desc table datasquare.users` and your Java code?

Comment: Aside: Do you really want to be storing your users' passwords in plain-text in the database?  Have you considered storing the hash of the password instead?  (There are a variety of ways to hash passwords.)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't ever run a query with `ALLOW FILTERING` in production.

Comment: im using jdbc driver

Comment: i have to change myquery or code

Answer (score 0):

You can't use count as a label

```
as count
```

Use instead total or something along the lines of

```
as total_users
```

or similar to avoid using a reserved keyword.

Comment: Actually, in Cassandra CQL `SELECT COUNT(*) as count` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Didn't see the tag.  But nonetheless the name implies either his column names in the where conditions are wrong or the column label is causing conflict.  Either his label is wrong or his table isn't exactly written as he demonstrated

Comment: i didn't get u...can be specific

Comment: Either your label selecting count(*) as count or the columns specified in the where conditions is causing your problem.  Ensure you don't have a typo in your where conditions and if not try a different label.